# How to get relative path instead of absolute path in compiler diagnostic messages

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

Is there a setting in make/cmake which changes the file path (/home/foo/code/sandbox/apps/main.cpp) from absolute to relative (and vice versa) in output?

When I run make, I see the following output:

```
$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object apps/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/foo/code/sandbox/apps/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/foo/code/sandbox/apps/main.cpp:4:3: error: ‘rintf’ was not declared in this scope
   rintf("Hello world\n");
   ^~~~~
/home/foo/code/sandbox/apps/main.cpp:4:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘printf’
   rintf("Hello world\n");
   ^~~~~
   printf
```

Comment: Unlikely; CMake hardcodes absolute paths for basically everything in the makefiles generated and the error you're seeing is not printed by (c)make itself, but by the compiler called as part of the build.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd suggest you research to see if existing questions have been asked for your _specific compiler_, and if you don't find anything, ask that question yourself.