# How to handle source dir paths introduced by __FILE__ in cmake?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, makefile

I'm using the `__FILE__` macro in my `main.cpp` file. When compiling with `make + Makefile`  the final executable `main` contains the string `main.cpp` (you can check it via `strings main | grep "*.cpp"`). But when using `cmake + CMakeLists.txt` `cmake` uses absolute paths and the final executable contains `/home/cpp/main.cpp`, so it causes the following warning (`makepkg`):

> ==> Checking for packaging issues...
>
> ==> WARNING: Package contains reference to $srcdir

What should I do in this case? Somehow tell `cmake` to not use absolute paths? Don't use the `__FILE__` macro (then, what?)? Ignore the warning?

Comment: Answer really depends on what you are using the macro `__FILE__` for.

Comment: First hit for `gcc __FILE__ relative` brought me straight back to SO. Please do the same before you ask questions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848526/1548468) for a way to strip the source path, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59154301/1548468) which proposes using `__FILE_NAME__`.

Comment: @john so, I can't handle it on `cmake` level and should inspect the sources? Can't I just tell `cmake` to use relative paths as `make` does?

Comment: @Botje thanks, there is an answer indeed. Actually, I found this question, but didn't read up to the 4th answer :)

Comment: @cppbest I didn't say that. I just said the right thing to do depends largely on what you are using `__FILE__` for.

Comment: "Can't I just tell cmake to use relative paths as make does?" - Such question has been [asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617239/make-relative-path-vs-absolute-path-in-output). As far as I know, CMake has no "switch" to generate relative paths in Makefile.